# Generator will not go through all files

Tags: python, dataframe, keras, generator

I am training a model with data from multiple `.csv` files and I find that my code reads through the files but the model still trains on a single one. The relevant parts of my code are:

```
def get_data(datasets_path):
    ''' 
    Returns the dataframes.
    '''
    full_path = datasets_path + "*.csv"
    for data_fname in glob.glob(full_path):
            df = pd.read_csv(data_fname)
            processed_df = __preprocessor(df)
            scaler = MinMaxScaler()
            transformed_df = scaler.fit_transform(processed_df)
            return transformed_df


def batch_generator(X, batch_size=16, shuffle=False):
    '''
    Return a random sample from X.
    '''
    count = 0
    while True:
        if shuffle:
            idx = np.random.randint(0, X.shape[0], batch_size)
            data = X[idx]
        else:
            indices = list(n for n in range(X.shape[0]))
            data = X[indices[count*batch_size : (count+1)*batch_size]]
            count +=1
        yield (data, data)
```

and

```
data = get_data(path_to_datasets)
x_train, x_test = train_test_split(data, test_size=0.2, random_state=42, shuffle=False)

x_train = np.expand_dims(x_train, axis=1)
x_test = np.expand_dims(x_test, axis=1)

train_gen = batch_generator(x_train, batch_size=32)
valid_gen = batch_generator(x_test, batch_size=32)
```

then I define a simple model and train it with

```
model.fit_generator(
    generator=train_gen,
    epochs=1,
    steps_per_epoch=x_train.shape[0] // 32,
    validation_data=valid_gen,
    validation_steps=x_test.shape[0] // 32)
```

The problem is that this seems to train from a single `.csv` file and not go through all of them, and I don't understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probelem is your return statement inside for loop. After processing single file the `get_data` method will break from loop. Try to use yield to get iterator.

```
def get_data(datasets_path):
    ''' 
    Returns the dataframes.
    '''
    full_path = datasets_path + "*.csv"
    for data_fname in glob.glob(full_path):
            df = pd.read_csv(data_fname)
            processed_df = __preprocessor(df)
            scaler = MinMaxScaler()
            transformed_df = scaler.fit_transform(processed_df)
            yield transformed_df
```